# Correlation between the gain and the activity level of a microphone object in flash/flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, volume, microphone, relation

The microphone's gain property is default at 50 and ranges from 0 to 100, It boosts the signal from the microphone.

The microphone activityLevel property also ranges from 0 to 100, and describes the volume of the recorded mic audio.

I need to know the correlation between boosting the signal and the activity level, which does have an effect on each other that I have tested. What does a gain of 100 mean?

Answer (score 1):

The [activityLevel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#activityLevel) property defines the sensitivity of the microphone - the range of sounds it will pick up - if you want it picking up everything it can, including background noise and quiet noises, assign this property to 100. If you want it picking up only LOUD noises, turn it to 0.

The [gain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#gain) is the strength of the amplification of the microphone's sound - 100 is the most, 0 is the least. Turning the gain up makes sound quality deteriorate (Depending on quality of equipment), while it gets louder.

Turning gain to 100 and activityLevel 0 means you're making Loud noises louder. Gain 0, `activityLevel` 100 means you're picking up every sound and not amplifying it.

Comment: This is all good but not discrete. I've made a script where I make the user say something specific into the microphone and press stop when he is done saying it. After the recording, I grab the average mic activity level, and based on this average I want to amplify the mic. Right now if the average is below 1, I set the gain to 100. What is the formula that relates the two

Comment: Anyway, <http://forums.adobe.com/message/1049449> has a suggestion for normalizing audio on flex, and really the gain is just a coefficient modifier for the current input. If the activityLevel(which is a relative value of how much input there is) is 0, 100 gain isn't really going to help amplify no sound.